# How to load child route without parent component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In question it looks pretty straightforward, but my case hard to explain in one question. Case itself: I want routing like following

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
      nothing: TranslationLoadResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/home/module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
      },
      // few more pages
      {
        path: 'major-documents/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/major-documents-details/module').then(m => m.MajorDocumentsDetailsModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

HomePageComponent contains lot of information, a little bit of every other page, kind of dashboard. There I have preview of "Major Documents" and I HAVEN'T page to list all of them, because there are only 3 of them and I display them in home page. But I want to show details  of those documents on own route 'major-documents/:id'. And I have routing configuration for MajorDocumentDetailsModule like this:
`export const documentsDetailsRoutes: Routes = [ { path: '', children: [ { path: '', component: MajorDocumentDetailsPage, } ] }, ];`
How I need to modify this routes to be able to move from "/home" to "/major-documents/:id" without having separate page for "/major-documents"?

I tried move `component: MajorDocumentDetailsPage` to parent route, tried to move ':id' param inside "documentsDetailsRoutes". It have to be working somehow but I definitely missing smth.

Answer (score 0):

use 3 routes in your router

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/home/module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  // ... other routes
  {
    path: 'major-documents/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/major-documents-details/module').then(m => m.MajorDocumentsDetailsModule),
  },
];
```

then  create a documentsDetailsRoutes

```
export const documentsDetailsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MajorDocumentDetailsPage
  }
];
```

navigate to /major-documents/1  will load the MajorDocumentsDetailsModule and display the details of the major document with the specified ID.